# How can I avoid the "last comma" gotcha (and similar) in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In the perl word (which I'm coming from), adding a final comma when creating an object does not have any bad side effects - in fact it's encouraged in case you want to add fields later;

[this article](http://perltricks.com/article/27/2013/6/16/Perl-hash-basics--create--update--loop--delete-and-sort/), (one of many possible sources) says:

```
my %weekly_temperature = (
    monday    => 65, 
    tuesday   => 68,
    wednesday => 71, 
    thursday  => 53, 
    friday    => 60,
);
```

*A couple more tips when working with key value pairs of a hash: the code is more readable if you vertically align the fat comma (‘=>’) operators and unlike C, Perl allows the last element to have a trailing comma, which makes it easier to add elements later without generating a compile error.*

In the javascript world - as I understand it - the last comma is advised against - again, a sample tip from [this (one of many) article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/seven-javascript-things-i-wish-i-knew-much-earlier-in-my-career/):

```
var car = {
  colour:'red',
  wheels:4,
  hubcaps:'spinning',
  age:4
}
```

*The main gotcha in this notation is IE. Never ever leave a trailing comma before the closing curly brace or you’ll be in trouble.*

How can I catch this and similar "gotcha's" in my javascript code?

Comment: did you look at jslint ?
or jshint ? or JSCS ?

Comment: Such tools are called "linters". Helps with Googling.

Comment: jslint adheres to Douglas Crockford's opinion (he warns you beforehand that jslint WILL hurt your feelings). Google's closure compiler is a minifier that can be run with a command line option to print warnings. Closure compiler adheres to Google's internal coding standards. YUIcompressor is another minifier that has an option to print out warnings adhering to Yahoo's internal coding standards. jshint can be configured to any standard

Comment: I've rephrased my question to more directly show the problem I want to address.  Could a moderator please reconsider the "on-hold" status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do javascript validation. I have a plugin that runs jslint in my IDE. We also have jslint running as a build task when we build our web application.

We even do gated check-in, failing the CI build if the javascript don't comply with the jslint validation, keeping a minimum level of integrity for our javascript code. Have a look at how to do this with your favourite build system.

Also, have a look at Gulp.js. It's a command line script tool that can trigger on save and run all kinds of tools, for instance javascript integrity tools like jshint or jscs.

Here's a tutorial on how to set up Gulp.js to do just that. You will need to install node.js first, as it uses NPM - the node package manager.

https://isimmons.github.io/